# API tira error desde consola en producción, pero funciona en pruebas con la misma data

Tags: c#, json, api

Tengo un problema  con respecto a una API que construí en C#, el tema es que en pruebas la API corre y manda los datos de la base de datos a otra base de datos; ahora, en producción cuando apunto la API hacia la URL productiva, en algunos casos me va bien y en otros me tira 500.

No sé a qué se deba porque las pruebas han funcionado correctamente, me han comentado que puede ser tema de CORS, pero no tengo la seguridad de ello.

Probando con POSTMAN el JSON en la API (va normal):

[image: postman]

En consola me tira error (con el mismo JSON):

```
Error en el servidor remoto: (500) Error interno en el servidor.
```

Comment: Vete al log de errores del servidor para encontrar más información sobre el error 500

Comment: No puedo entrar en el servidor ni al log, es producción y no tengo acceso a ello.

Comment: Pues entonces no puedes saber con certeza que le está pasando al servidor y tendrás que ir probando cosas a ver si así funcionan hasta acertar.  ¿no puedes contactar con el admin del servidor para que te lo mire?  ¿o es una web de terceros que no tiene relación contigo directamente?

Comment: Si tengo relación, pero la comunicación es muy tardía y además por temas de seguridad no comparten la información sensible del servidor. En resumen, no tengo acceso a esa data que me dices.